Bounds for Complex Moduli

Let $z$ be a complex number such that $\left|z+\dfrac{1}{z}\right|=a, a>0$
. Find the minimum and maximum value of |z|.

This question has been asked before, but I am wondering what the issue is with a different approach:
I first square both sides and simplify.
$$\left|z\right|^{2}+\frac{1}{\left|z\right|^{2}}+2Re\left(\frac{z}{z̄}\right)=a^2$$
Now, I use the fact that: $-\left|z^*\right|\le Re\left(z^*\right)\le\left|z^*\right|$
Thus, $a^{2}-2\le\left|z\right|^{2}+\frac{1}{\left|z\right|^{2}}\le a^{2}+2$.
However, only the right inequality leads to the correct answer. Can someone please explain why?

There's no reason to believe in advance that the value of $z$ on $|z+\frac1z|=a$ that maximizes $|z|$ on that curve also has the property that it's the value of $z$ that achieves equality in Re$(z) \le |z|$; and there's no reason to believe in advance that the value of $z$ on $|z+\frac1z|=a$ that minimizes $|z|$ on that curve also has the property that it's the value of $z$ that achieves equality in Re$(z) \ge -|z|$. So we shouldn't expect this argument to necessarily get best-possible bounds (although it certainly gets valid bounds).
It's just a happy coincidence that in the first case, it is the same value of $z$.
